# Java Scheduler to Mail

Tags: java, spring, email, backend, scheduler

Given that I have two scheduled component classes uploading files respectively.
I created a sending email method for each of them in order to send a reminder email to myself in case any uploading exceptions happened.

the flow like this:

Scheduler One   --- if exception during uploading ---> sending a email after exception

Scheduler Two   --- if exception during uploading ---> sending a email after exception

now I want to upgrade as

Scheduler One + Scheduler Two
--if exception--> sending a mail after two scheduler

Nonetheless, how can I do that?

Comment: The fact that you want to know the additive outcome suggests that the two tasks are not as independent as you thought, so this is in fact a design problem. But since you are a professional developer, logging will be built into both tasks, so a kludge would be to watch the two log files and send an email where necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use case sounds really odd. Schedulers run independent. So if you want to share information (an exception was thrown) between both thos you have to store this information somewhere. A entry in a database or saving in in a global variable during runtime.

I would however suggest that you merge both of you scheduler into one. If they are not independent why divide the code? It saves you from creating theses hacks where the schedulers need to be connected